# Заполнение массива рекурсивным методом

Tags: java

Нужно сделать рекурсивный метод при котором бы заполнялся и выводился массив, но ошибки уже при вводе.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Massiv {

public static int[] arr = new int[10];
static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
public static int x = 0;
public static int Mass(int n)
{
    if (x == 10)
    {
        return arr[10];
    }
    else 
    {
        System.out.println("Введите " + (x+1) + " элемент массива");
        int c = in.nextInt();
        arr[x] = c;
        x+=1;   
    }  
    return Mass(x);
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Mass(10);
}}
```

В итоге вроде он заполняется, но когда доходит до 10 происходит переполнение массива.
Как это можно исправить ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Одним из вариантов решения, близким к вашему коду, будет передача `n` (предельное кол-во элементов) в качестве аргумента рекурсивной функции и проверка условия `(x == n)` для выхода из рекурсии.
В качестве возвращаемого функцией значения целесообразно использовать `return arr`, то есть массив целиком, а не отдельный его элемент с индексом, превышающем предельный `return arr[10];` (здесь и возникала ошибка).

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static int[] arr = new int[10];
    static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static int x = 0;

    public static int[] Mass(int n) {
        if (x == n) return arr;
        else {
            System.out.print("Введите " + (x + 1) + " элемент массива: ");
            arr[x++] = in.nextInt();
        }
        return Mass(n);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] out = Mass(10);
        for (int el : out) System.out.print(el + " ");
    }
}
```

```
Введите 1 элемент массива: 1
Введите 2 элемент массива: 2
Введите 3 элемент массива: 3
Введите 4 элемент массива: 4
Введите 5 элемент массива: 5
Введите 6 элемент массива: 6
Введите 7 элемент массива: 7
Введите 8 элемент массива: 8
Введите 9 элемент массива: 9
Введите 10 элемент массива: 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Надо вспомнить что при инициализации массива ты указываешь размер [10]
Но почему-то забываешь что твой массив при этом индексируется с 0 до 9.
т.о. обращение к 11 ячейке массива с индексом 10 приводит к ошибке.